# Tenserflow.js Error: The JSON from HTTP path data.json contains neither model topology or manifest for weights

Tags: javascript

I exported coco formatted json file from datatorch but it returns the error message(title of this post)

This is how i loaded the json file
let MODEL_FILE_URL = "data.json";
tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL).then(function(loadedModel) { model = loadedModel; });

Comment: You already tried use loadLayersModel? (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781838821739/7c1c4e42-5143-4f39-8c30-747f31c92990.xhtml)